# Accessing webService via SoapUI : ERROR gatewayRequest

Tags: web-services, websphere, apache-axis

I'm trying to test a web service via SOAPUI, and i'm getting this error :

com.ibm.ctg.client.GatewayRequest

By web service uses Axis2 and is deployed on webSphere 7.

Does anyone have any idea?? 
Thanks for your help, appreciated

Comment: Is there an exception (ideally with an accompanying stack trace) in your server logs (e.g. SystemOut.log)?  It's certainly possible that the class name there is just the message text of the exception (for example, if it's a ClassNotFoundException or something to that effect), but it's not really possible to do much debug with that on its own.

Comment: I have figure it out eventually, the jar ctgclient.jar was missing in my lib folder. hope it will help someone else.